# Magento 2 - can't register custom module

Tags: module, magento2

I created a module.xml under the app/code/my/module/etc folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="my_module" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

Than I tried to enable the module with following command

```
php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content my_module
```

And get this error:

> Unknown module(s): 'my_module'

Why don't Magento find the module?

---

Here is the error after executing the flush command:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace.

---

Now here is the error:

Additionally to the xml syntax in the module.xml I added comments. These comments caused the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you have to first clear the cache by running the following command.

```
php -f bin/magento cache:clean
```

or

```
php -f bin/magento cache:flush
```

Then as you executed cache commands, it is possible that permissions are revoked on many files which are being executed during module enabling and disabling.

So if you're on linux(Ubuntu/Debian) then provide full permissions to your root magento directory as below:

```
cd /path/to/magento2
sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

Then, provided you've already created 'registration.php' file in your module directory(magento2root/app/code/My/Module/) like below,

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'my_module',
    __DIR__
);
```

run the module enable command you mentioned in your question.

It is not mandatory to have 'composer.json' for module enable-disable, composer.json is needed for git-based tasks(commit module code/update module code etc.) if you have active repo of your site at [Github](https://github.com/).

Comment: I've tried everything with the registration.php and composer.json, but nothing works. I also get the following error if I try to execute the flush command: php -f bin/magento cache:flush

I've got the following error:
There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace.

Comment: That's because there is some syntax error or exception in your current module(the module you're trying to register) or any other module you've installed previously. I got this error many times and everytime it was some syntax issue(any variable/object used without declaration or extending unavailable/invalid class), please check all your code (in app/code dir)thoroughly for any kind of syntax or typos. Are you using Magento 2.0.0 stable release ?

Comment: Yes I Do. I downloaded it from the magento page.

Comment: Well then do check all the installed modules of app/code dir for any syntax issues. Once those are resolved then the steps in my answer should work all-right. They are working for me already.

Comment: Ok, also I see from your screenshot, you're using Windows with Xampp installed, right ? Well then you have to provide full permission to magento2root dir for user "www-data", permissions and syntax-error-free code are necessary for the magento2 commands to run successfully.

Comment: I got comments in the module.xml file. This caused the error. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a registration.php file in /app/code/my/module ?

If not, do, and add this to it:

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'my_module',
    __DIR__
);
```

you'll also need a composer.json in the same directory:

```
{
"name": "my/module",
"description": "my module for Magento 2",
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0"
},
"type": "magento2-module",
"version": "1.0.0",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
        "my\\module\\": ""
    }
}
}
```

Then re-run:

```
php bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content my_module
```

Comment: Yes I did. See comment below.

Answer (score 0):

once you created your module you need to deploy,

run following command \bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy
OR open   app/etc folder add 'my_module' => 1 in config.xml, and clear the cache.